# Open Sets in Metric Spaces ($C[0,1]$)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the set below an open set on the maximum metric in C[0,1]?

$\{f\in C[0,1]: f(1)=7\}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not, if that set is called $A$ and $f \in A$, then suppose $B(f,r) \subseteq A$ for some $r>0$: but then $f+\frac{r}{2}$ is continuous and has distance $\frac r2$ to $f$ so lies in $B(f,r)$ but is not in $A$ as its value at $1$ is $7+\frac r2$ and not $7$, contradiction.

In fact $A$ is nowhere dense: it's closed and has empty interior.

Comment: I sensed it wasn't off, but I couldn't choose r. Thank you very much.